# Backing Up Multiple SQL Databases to Network Share at the Same Time

Tags: sql-server, backup, database, database-backup

Junior SysAdmin/accidental DBA here so apologies in advance for the noob question.

The previous DBA here had a SQL Backup Maintenance Plan that he would copy across 20+ database servers and have all of the full backups kick off at 10pm.

All of these backups are going to a one single network share location. Is there anything that I should be concerned about here with the amount of open connections to that network share?

There haven't been any issues thus far but I am looking to copy this Maintenance Plan to some additional servers soon so that all of the jobs are uniform across the board.

Comment: Is that network share on-premises, and is it backed up off-site?

Comment: @ceejayoz yes network share is on premise and yes it is backed up off site.

Comment: if all the backups are in a single maintenance plan, it will backup one database at a time. the only problem you may have would be if you have multiple jobs schedule to run at the same time.

Comment: btw, I would highly recommend SQL Backup from RedGate. it makes it really easy to coordinate schedule times across multiple servers.

Comment: @RicardoC just for clarification I have the following scenario:

DBServer1 with DatabaseA & DatabaseB set to backup at 10pm via Maintenance Plan to NetworkShare1

DBServer2 with DatabaseC & DatabaseD set to backup at 10pm via Maintenance Plan to NetworkShare1

I understand that in a single maintenance plan, it will backup one database at a time. However, if I have a maintenance plan on 2 different servers that kicks off at the same time, is this a cause for concern even though they are backing up to their own individual folders on that network share?

Comment: as a personal opinion and with no load testing done to the IO of your network storage, I say 'it is ok' a network storage device 'should' be able to handle the load. and since the maintenance jobs are run on different server, you dont have to worry about the SQL Server work load itself (unless they are VMs in the same host). Again, many factors may fafect this 'opinion' (hopefully not to cause and internet flame attack >.< lol )